# What do these symbols mean in XML .DTD? "?" "+" and "|"

Tags: xml, dtd

I got this exercise for school in which I should write an XML file for this .dtd file but I dont know and cant find the meaning of the marked symbols. Does anyone know the meaning of them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1PHv.png)